# A weird issue with UUIDs, when using mongodb .net driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an odd issue with mongodb .net driver.
When using source code listed below, all properties in TestObject are stored as UUID, except

"guid" property in dictionary.

So, default behavior with `BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));` yields following result in mongo. As you can see only one guid is stored as binary. Rest are UUIDs.
[image]

But, when I use

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

It yields following result in mongo. As you can see, all guids are stored as UUID. So, why behaviors are different in the first case?
While I do not have an issue using `BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;`

, it's marked as an Obsolete, so I would need to know what is the solution for this issue, since I want all guids to be stored as UUIDs.

[image]

Any idea how can I fix this?

Full source:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
//BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard; //uncomment to work properly


// Create a MongoClient object.
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

// Get your database (replace "yourDatabase" with your database name).
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

// Get your collection (replace "yourCollection" with your collection name).
var collection = database.GetCollection<TestObject>("guids");

TestObject testObject = new TestObject
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "aaaaaaaaaa",
    Guids = new List<Guid>()
    {
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid()
    },
    Objects = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    
};

testObject.Objects.Add("guids", new List<Guid>()
    {
        Guid.NewGuid(),
        Guid.NewGuid()
    });

testObject.Objects.Add("guid", Guid.NewGuid());


// Insert the TestObject instance into the collection.
collection.InsertOne(testObject);

Console.WriteLine("TestObject inserted successfully.");

Console.ReadKey();



public class TestObject
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

 
    public IEnumerable<Guid> Guids { get; set; }

   

 public Dictionary<string, object> Objects { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This seems a bit off indeed... I can imagine that the driver uses a different method when serializing the GUIDs in `Dictionary<string, object>` as it adds the type discriminator. Might be worth reporting it (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/issues-and-help/).

Comment: @Markus i've reported here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4987  Will that suffice?

Comment: yes I think so :-)

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77393925/9492730. This behavior related to guid representation mode

Comment: and more details can be found here: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/reference/bson/guidserialization/guidrepresentationmode/v3mode/

Comment: @dododo yes, but that field is marked obsolete and therefore discouraged from future use. What if it's removed, and issue not fixed (or decided it's not an issue at all)

Comment: It's not true. There is another reason to mark something obsolete. In addition to obvious one, it can be done to simply remove something in next release. In this case, it means removing V2/V3 switch configuration, not V3 functionality. As I know, starting from next major release, only mode V3 will be available and therefore no switch class will be required anymore. Read documentation I posted above

Comment: @dododo thanks. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/serialization/guid-serialization/#serializing-objects-in-v3  i guess this is also solution :facepalm:

Comment: the above link also says about V3 mode

Comment: @Robert sorry for pointing you towards Jira - I was not aware that you have to configure the serializer for the objects differently. I hope that version 3.x of the driver will reduce the amount of configuration that is necessary to handle GUIDs correctly.

Comment: @Markus no problem. It's kinda clumsy design, because it serializes List<guid> well when stored in object type, but not guid itself.
Easy to make a mistake